# Sort data after letters first, then digits

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

Example:

```
32 BB
12 A
84 H
13 H
34 C
16 C
115 H
18 C
```

I want to order them like this:

```
12 A
32 BB
16 C
18 C
34 C
13 H
84 H
115 H
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
ORDER BY IF(data_name RLIKE '^[a-z]', 2, 3), data_name
```

That SQL query sorts them similar to how they are unsorted. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Try ORDER BY IF(data_name RLIKE '^[a-z]', 4,2), data_name

Comment: What database are you using?  Is the data in one column or two?

Comment: Same result, Grantly. I think I am using MariaDB, Gordon. Either that or InnoDB. I tried to look it up before I posted the question, but didn't find it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is in two columns (which is how I interpret the question and sample data), then simply do:

```
order by col2, col1
```

If the data is in one column, then I will guess from the `rlike` that you are using MySQL, you can do:

```
order by substring_index(col, ' ', -1), substring_index(col, ' ', 1) + 0
```

Comment: Many thanks! Your answer worked perfectly! If I had the values in two columns, I wouldn't ask you guys ;)

Comment: One more question though. How can I sort it backwards? So `115 H` comes first in the list, and `12 A` last?

Comment: @Erik . . . You put `DESC` after each `order by` key.